# Change PowerShell PSReadLine MenuComplete function's colors

Tags: powershell, psreadline

I am currently playing with the `PSReadLine` module options in PowerShell. In particular I am setting up a custom color theme. I have been able to set most of the colors I require using the following syntax as an example:
`Set-PSReadLineOption -TokenKind Variable -ForegroundColor DarkYellow`

However when I use the `MenuComplete` function of the `PSReadLine` module by pressing `Ctrl+Spacebar` the suggestions are highlighted in `DarkGreen` and I cannot seem to find a way to change these colors.

Comment: Which PoSh/PSReadline version? Here the command is `Set-PSReadLineOption -TokenKind Variable -ForegroundColor DarkYellow`

Comment: Sorry @LotPings that was just a typo on my part. I've corrected it now. PowerShell is v5, PSReadLine v1.1 which is shipped with Windows 10.

Comment: Win10 Build 15063 has PowerShell v5.1 PSReadLine v1.2 PowerShell v6.0.0 Beta3 comes also with PSReadLine v1.2

Comment: I am on Windows 10 1511 (OS Build 10586.962) which has PowerShell v5.0 and PSReadLine v1.1.

Comment: I'm not sure the versions are an issue. I am just unable to find a way to change the color of the `MenuComplete` function output.

Comment: Well my question regarding the version was because of the naming difference. I know PSReadLine was introduced  with PS v5.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see this option in the old color settings, but as of [6.1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-6), you can change the color of `Selection` like this:

```
$colors = @{
   "Selection" = "$([char]0x1b)[38;2;0;0;0;48;2;178;255;102m"
}

Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors $colors
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to make these settings persist? https://superuser.com/questions/1521541/set-psreadline-colors-and-then-persist-them

Comment: Can you explain the format of the color? I can't find anything.

Comment: @Holt, it's referenced in the documentation on the -Colors parameter that I linked. It is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors